# Why can I not invoke this function at module-level?

Tags: python, scope

**Issue** [python 3.8.6]

```
def __foo():
    pass

class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        __foo()

MyClass.bar()
```

results in:

```
NameError: name '_MyClass__foo' is not defined
```

**Observations**

- If I replace `__foo()` with `foo()`, it runs fine.
- I realize python is looking for `__foo()` inside `MyClass`.  In C++, I can use `::__foo()` to explicitly invoke the function at the module level.  Is there an equivalent in python?

**Questions**

- Can you explain why I'm getting this error?
- How can I keep `__foo()` and invoke it from inside the Class?

**RESOLUTION**

I had a misunderstanding about naming conventions in python.

*Private* methods and symbols in classes have *double underscore prefixes*, but the same symbols at the module level have *single underscore prefixes*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To limit the scope of the function to the module.  It also works if I add it as a suffix.  I need to find the rules for proper naming in python.

Comment: That doesn't limit the scope of the function to the module... why do you think it does? *Conventionally* non-public parts of the API use a *single* underscore.

Comment: Thx - single underscore also works.  Can you point me to some documentation that describes all the underscore conventions?  Thank you.

Comment: You cannot. You can prevent certain names from being improted when using starred imports, although, you should generally avoid starred imports anyway. Conventionally, you should just use a single underscore (which will automatically be excluded from starred imports, and most python-based tooling, e.g. tab completion, understand that and won't show it)

Comment: I'm also trying to use underscore for documentation purposes.  Reading code, it's useful to know which symbols are meant to be only used within a module and which symbols are meant to be used by applications outside the module.

Comment: See my answer. You should use a single underscore. Unless you are purposefully trying to prevent name-colllisoins in classes (particularly in the context of inheritance) then don't use two leading underscores in your names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because *any* name with two underscores as a prefix (and not a suffix) is mangled inside a class definition statement. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

> **“Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from
> inside an object don’t exist in Python**. However, there is a convention
> that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an
> underscore (e.g. `_spam`) should be treated as a non-public part of the
> API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should
> be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without
> notice.
>
> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to
> avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there
> is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. *Any
> identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at
> most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
> `_classname__spam`*, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. *This mangling is done without regard
> to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs
> within the definition of a class.*

(emphasis added)

The *sanest* thing is not to name your function with two underscores. Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
def __foo():
    pass

def bar():
    __foo()


class MyClass:
    bar = staticmethod(bar)


MyClass.bar()
```

Or honestly, just keep `bar` as a module-level function.

But again, using two-underscores doesn't make much sense. If you meant to signal that the function is not a part of the public api of the module, then you should use a *single* underscore:

```
def _foo():
    pass
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you - didn't know that python uses __ to mangle method names.  I will use single underscore.

Comment: @kfmfe04 yeah that can definitely be confusing if you aren't aware

Comment: Yeah - I got thrown off, because I was using double underscore for private static methods inside a class.  Thought that rule also applied to the module level - I was wrong!

Comment: @kfmfe04 very important to understand, *python doesn't have private methods*. As the quoted part of the docs states. However, to signal "this is private" use a *single* underscore in your method names